# SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier Python 3.5.2 & tensorflow

Tags: python, error-handling

i am now starting to learn about tensorflow..was following along with a youtube vid on this and followed the program but getting a SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier -line 53 sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())...see program below..any assistance appreciated:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

n_nodes_hl1 = 500
n_nodes_hl2 = 500
n_nodes_hl3 = 500

n_classes = 10
batch_size = 100

#height x width
x = tf.placeholder('float',[None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder('float')


def neural_network_model(data):
    hidden_1_layer = {'weights' :tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, n_nodes_hl1])),'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

    hidden_2_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

    hidden_3_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

    output_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

    # (input_data * weights) + biases

    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output = tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']

    return output

def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    hm_epochs = 10

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())﻿

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)):
                epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of', hm_epochs, 'loss:', epoch_loss)

        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct,'float'))
        print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:mnist.test.images, y:mnist.test.labels}))


    train_neural_network(x)
```

Comment: Could your issue be using the underscore character for the looping? It seems like an odd way to loop, especially because as an outsider it looks like a variable name chosen with no significance.

Comment: That's the normal way to say you're not using the variable.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error some time ago. Please don't copy paste the code from different editors or web pages. If you type it in you editor, it won't give you that error.

Answer (score 0):

It is because copying code and pasting it lead to copying of spaces also. Remove spaces and add spaces manually around the identifier code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains unprintable and invalid characters. You can fix it by manually retyping it.

```
# copied and pasted from your code
s1 = 'sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())﻿'

# manually typed
s2 = 'sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())'
```

The two strings look identical but they are not. Using `repr` we can see the difference:

```
print(repr(s1))                                                        
'sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())\ufeff'

print(repr(s2))                                                        
'sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())'
```

The extra character in `s1`is a [ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm). Wondering where that came from.